# Call JavaScript function both submitting form and clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have function which should be called both when submitting the form and clicking the button. I've tried doing this by following code, but I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery and can't handle the situation.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" form="orderForm">
    Save
</button>
<button type="submit" form="saveandlock" onsubmit="saveOrderItems()" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    Send order
</button>
```

The form with `id="orderForm"` has `action="#"` and another with `id="saveandlock"` has `action="orders.php"`.

**JavaScript**

```
function saveOrderItems(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if(result == "1") {
                moveToOrder();
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$(document).on("submit", "form#orderForm", function (event) {
    saveOrderItems(event);
});
```

Maybe you can help me to learn and I can do this myself next time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't very clear. "both when submitting the form and clicking the button" Isn't clicking the button submits the form? Also, the "onsubmit" inline event handler assignment works for <form> only, not <button>.

Comment: By the way, instead of writing `function (event) { saveOrderItems(event); });` you could just write `saveOrderItems` directly.

Comment: @marekful, I use Ajax to save form items when clicking "Save" button. Another button "Send" just sets order status to "locked", but before it happens I'd like to save items using function with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

.on() can handle multiple events...

```
$(document).on('submit click', 'form#orderForm', function(event) {
    saveOrderItems(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for a submit button OnSubmit and OnClick is completely different,

Try confirm prompt in JS function itself

```
<button type="submit" form="saveandlock" onclick="saveOrderItems()" >
    Send order
</button>
```

and your form HTML

```
<form onsubmit="saveOrderItems()">
  //your content here
</form>
```

and in your JS

```
  function saveOrderItems(event) {
    var confirmed = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (confirmed ) {
     //your other actions here
    }
  }
```

Comment: It has no effect if I select yes or no, form will be submitted. I added `return false;` after `if (confirmed) {}` - no effect. And it says that `event` is undefined.

Comment: Ok, it works almost correctly by doing this. But button which submits form `saveandlock` doesn't work. If I have `onclick="saveOrderItems()` button executes the function, but doesn't submit the form. I want that it executes the function and after that submits the form.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this sample and tell the result:

```
<button type="submit" form="orderForm" id="btn1">Save</button>
<button type="submit" form="saveandlock" id="btn2">Send order</button>
<!-- I have added new IDs to both buttons -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.fn.saveOrderItems = function(){
      // function codes here
   }

   $('#btn1, #btn2').click(function(e){
      answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
      if (!answer) {
          e.preventDefault();
      } else {
          $.fn.saveOrderItems();
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, I wanted to show how to build user defined functions and using multiple selectors in jQuery. This is what questioner asked. And I think it is not terrible at all.

Comment: But adding a function to `$.fn` [makes it a method of all JQuery objects](http://jsfiddle.net/oej69rwc/), which makes no sense in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If you keep the actual saving code in its own function instead of writing it directly in an event listener, you can always call it from another piece of code.

Make a function called `saveForm` that does not use the `event` object (make it require exactly what it needs as a parameter if you need to, but not the whole event). Then, you can call it from both the save button's click event and the form's submit. For example:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(event) {
    saveForm($(this));
    // submits after saving (if saveForm is not async)
});

$('#savebutton').on('click', function(event) {
    saveForm($('#myform'));
});
```